# any one know how i add file manager to asp.net ajax toolkit editor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

any one know file manager for asp.net ajax toolkit editor?
i know there is other editors but i want know if ajax toolkit editor can have file or/and image manager .
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax toolkit editor did not have any image insert to need file manage.

So its not the file manager but the full idea to insert image or other items using file manager.

So its better for me to use other editors if you need to insert an image for example, and so you need a file manage...

google: **asp.net web editor** and you find few...